# Eranger Montana Ladies E-Bike

Tags: road-bike, electric-bike

Bike now 4 years old and battery not holding charge like when first purchased. Been n touch with Eranger cannot help said bike no longer being produced so now left with a £1100 bike and cannot buy a new battery. Any suggestions where I can get a new battery appreciated.

Comment: The chances are it consists of 18650 li-ion cells commonly used in power tools / laptop batteries. They will probably be arranged in series to get the voltage. It may be worth looking for battery repair rather than replacement.

Comment: See if there isn't a shop that specializes in batteries in your area.  In the US we have shops like "Batteries Plus" and they are often able to rebuild failed batteries for relatively reasonable cost.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the problem with new technologies is that it is difficult to have a universal standard. Also the as the technology improves things get smaller  stronger,cheaper,etc. This causes items to become obsolete quickly. In the U.S. there are several  battery specific retailers (Interstate Battery for one) that have the ability to repair or rebuild batteries packs. They open the case replace damaged or worn out cells and reassemble them. This can be a pricey purchase . My employer spent $800 U.S. for a rebuilt battery pack for a Infra-Red camera that was $14,000 when new. In that case, a worthwhile investment. Depending on how many damaged cells need replacement it it may or not be cost efficient in your case.